# How to convert a formatted number to 2 decimal places and maintain a float return type

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch data from a database, using json. but the data retrieve from the database is of type String which is causing an error.

What I want to do is to format the data to a float type with 2 decimal places.

I have gone through similar probable answers, but none seems to solve the challenge.

This is what I have done.

```
$num1 = "9";

//Using number_format
echo (float) number_format($num1,2,'.',''); // result is 9 instead of 9.00

//Using Floatval
echo floatval("9"); // result is 9 instead of 9.00
```

How can I get the result formatted as 9.00 ?

Comment: You can either have the float `9` or you can have the string representation of `9` as `9.00`.  Store it as a float and then use `number_format()` or other when needed to format it for display etc...

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the (float) inside the number_format.

```
echo number_format((float) $num, 2, '.','');
```

Comment: Thanks @P.Gearman, but the return type of the number_format will still be a string. I need a float. 
$num = "9"; 
echo $num2 = number_format((float) $num, 2, '.','');
echo gettype($num2);

Comment: If you use
    $new_num = floatval($num);
that will get you a variable of type double. You could then use
    number_format($new_num, 2, '.', '');
to get the formatted number.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `echo number_format ((float) $num1, 2, '.', '');`

the format of this is: `string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )` from http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

another method is: `sprintf('%0.2f', $num1);`

and sprintf is used to format strings and might be applicable in other areas as well. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: Thanks @ViperCode, I need a float data type as the final value.

Comment: @CyrusOlu That makes no sense. `echo` just displays the number, it doesn't change the value of anything.